# pandas tolist() how to return different data types?

Tags: python, list, pandas, series

I want to convert a data frame to a list before I pass it to a dictionary. I am using the following code:

```
df[['date','LTP']].iloc[0:1].values.tolist()
```

This works fine but the data type it returns is the same for both series. Both series are doubles although I want an int and a double.

```
[[1472688000000.0, -0.7222783810000001]]
```

If it try to use astype() that also applies to both series.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I don't think arrays contain mixed types unless you explicitly specify that to be the case: `df[['date','LTP']].iloc[0:1].astype(object).values.tolist()`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say "pass to dictionary" - but note that in Python dictionary keys are lenient, e.g. for `d = {1.00: 'hello'}` you'll find `d[1]` returns `'hello'`.

Comment: It is then passed as dictionary values. But for my application, integers must keep their data type. so basically the list i'm creating needs to needs to have both data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a list of tuples is acceptable, you can use `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1472688000000, -0.7222783810000001]],
                  columns=['date', 'LTP'])

x = df[['date','LTP']].iloc[0:1]

res = list(zip(x.date, x.LTP))

print(res)

[(1472688000000, -0.72227838100000008)]
```

If you really need a list of lists, you can use:

```
res = list(map(list, zip(x.date, x.LTP)))
```

Or use @coldspeed's suggestion to go via `numpy`.